# Read permission of installed Application in android phone?

Tags: java, android, apk, android-permissions

I want to read permission of other applications installed in my android mobile  using programming.

I think [Android Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gn.cleanmaster)  read permission of other apps and display details like

[image]

I want get detail like this Image.

In this it's give details of **Ad Network**

How i get details like this app in my app?

**If this app not Read Permission then How it's do it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can scrape the playstore app page for a given app and get the permissions it needs :)

Well that's just off the top of my head. On a serious note, you can do the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List appsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

for (Object app : appsList) {
    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = (ResolveInfo) app;
    PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
    try {
        packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
}
```

Comment: i don't want to get permission of this app. but i want to get permission use by all apps

Comment: That's what I meant. Query the installed apps, get their package name and construct the playstore listing URL and scrape.

Comment: how i do it  ?  i already got all package name. but how i construct with playstore?

Comment: it's i know but i want details in offline mode